# Why is the potential solution the static one when the electric fields varies "slowly"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

If the potential between two conductors changes with a certain frequency, I understand that the potential and electric fields can be obtained by solving Laplace's Equation only if the frequency is "not too high". What would a mathematical argument look like ? I guess the solution lies in the expression of $\nabla \times \textbf{B}$.

-Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three common regimes of the Maxwell equations: the electrostatic, magnetostatic and electromagnetic regime. In the electrostatic limit $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} \approx 0$ which allows to define a electrostatic potential. In the magnetostatic limit $\nabla \times \mathbf{H} \approx 0$ (if currents are neglected) which allows to define a magnetic scalar potential. Hence, in the quasi-static regimes, the electric and magnetic fields are decoupled from each other. In the electromagnetic regime, on the other hand, nothing can be neglected and the electric and magnetic field are coupled (forming electromagnetic waves).

Concrete for your question, if you vary the potential very slow, then $\partial \mathbf{E} /\partial t$ is small and thus generates a very weak magnetic field via the relation $\nabla \times \mathbf{H} =\varepsilon_0 \partial \mathbf{E} /\partial t$. This generated magnetic field is too weak to generate any "back-action" on the electric field via $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} =\mu_0 \partial \mathbf{H} /\partial t \approx 0$. So, we end up in the electrostatic approximation.